# Reading files from SFTP with file name filter on poll basis in mule

Tags: groovy, mule, sftp, polling

I am using groovy script with file name filter to read file from SFTP location on Poll basis using below code

```
 <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <schedulers:cron-scheduler expression="${payment.schedule}"/>
            <scripting:transformer doc:name="Groovy">
                <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                    <scripting:text><![CDATA[    
            def endpointBuilder = muleContext.endpointFactory.getEndpointBuilder( 
                    "sftp://${sftp.user}:${sftp.password}@${sftp.host}:${sftp.port}/${sftp.root.path}") 
                    endpointBuilder.addMessageProcessor(new org.mule.routing.MessageFilter(new org.mule.transport.file.filters.FilenameWildcardFilter('payment_*'))) 
                    def inboundEndpoint = endpointBuilder.buildInboundEndpoint() 
                    inboundEndpoint.request(3000L) ;
                    ]]></scripting:text>
                </scripting:script>
            </scripting:transformer>
</poll>
```

Issue which I am facing here is that, Its reading only one file on each poll schedule. 
However, my expectation is, it should read all the file which satisfies the condition of filter from SFTP location on each poll schedule.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using the SFTP poller directly? https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/sftp-connector

Comment: Because it does not support filtering file with specific file name. That can be achieve using groovy scripts.

Comment: Yes it does ;) I'll post an example

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the SFTP Inbound Endpoint with `file:filename-wildcard-filter` instead of relying on a Groovy script wrapped in a poll. Such as:

```
<sftp:inbound-endpoint host="${sftp.host}" port="${sftp.port}" path="/home/test/sftp-files" user="${sftp.user}" password="${sftp.password}"> 
    <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="payment_*"/> 
</sftp:inbound-endpoint>
```

See the [related example in SFTP documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/sftp-transport-reference#example-sftp-to-file-flow).

Comment: Would it start processing of all files at one poll schedule?

Comment: Yes, it will poll all files at once respecting your pattern. Try it for yourself ;)

Comment: Thanks Pierre. I did not know about filename-wildcard-filter in SFTP connector.

Comment: Great, the underlying classes are probably the same than the one you defined in your Groovy script, but it is built-in in XML and officially documented. If that helped you solve your issue, feel free to upvote and/or accept ;)